# JReplacing all instance of a word in a string with another word without using replace()

Tags: java

How to replace all instances of a word in a string with another word without using replace(). Here is the code that I tried.
This code printed nothing.

```java
public class replaceWord {
  public static String replaceWord(String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    String result = "";
    for (int test = 0; test <= length-5; test++) {
        if (s.substring(test, test + 5).equals("Python")) {
            result += s.substring(0, test) + " Java " + s.substring(test + 5, length);
        }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test = "Oh my god I love Python so much!";
    System.out.println(replaceWord(test));
  }
}
```

Comment: ...........and?

Comment: It did not print anything. Sorry should have been more specific.

Comment: Have you done any debugging, for example, printing out what `s.substring(test, test +5)` is and so on?

Comment: Yes, also prints nothing.

Comment: Take a look at the Java class "StringBuilder".    Also, I have a feeling there's a problem lurking with the logic; your "from" and "to" words are clearly distinct, but what if they have substrings in common?

Comment: python has 6 letters

Comment: What's wrong with replaceAll? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other problems with your code.

- If the input string has more than one copy of the string to be replaced (e.g. "Java") in it, then the entire input string will be duplicated.
- If the input string contains zero copies of the string to be replaced, the output will be an empty string.

The problem is the `result += ...` statement.  Basically, this approach only works if there is exactly one copy of the string to be replaced.  You need to rethink ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your use of `substring`, the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) states the following for the method:

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the
> character at index endIndex - 1.

Therefore, to get a string "Python" which is 6 characters long you should use:

```
s.substring(test, test + 6).equals("Python")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can solve your problem in one line

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "Oh my god I love Python so much!";
    System.out.println(String.join("Java", test.split("Python")));
}
```

Output:

```
Oh my god I love Java so much!
```

Comment: You could also use `replaceAll()` ;)